# Does Oracle's SDO_Geometry spatial type support arcs?

Tags: geometry, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

*Oracle 18c GDB; ArcGIS 10.7.1*

---

With ESRI native spatial types, such as SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, we can store "CAD" arcs in the geometry of polyline and polygon features.

[image]

Question:

Does Oracle's SDO_Geometry spatial type support support arcs as well?

Comment: Oracle does have documentation about that https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-object-type.htm#SPATL489.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

From the Oracle docs:  [Valid SDO_GTYPE Values](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-object-type.htm#:%7E:text=DL02-,LINE%20or%20CURVE,-Geometry%20contains%20one)

> **DL02: LINE or CURVE**
>
> Geometry contains one line string that can contain straight or
> circular arc segments, or both. (LINE and CURVE are synonymous in this
> context.)

> **DL06: MULTILINE or MULTICURVE**
>
> Geometry has one or more line strings. (MULTILINE and MULTICURVE are
> synonymous in this context, and each is a superset of both LINE and
> CURVE.)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer might be incorrect. See @Vince's comment.

---

From a quick test, it looks like the answer is ***yes***.

I was able to create a polyline with an arc in an SDO_GEOMETRY FC.

- In my case, I simply copied a SDE.ST_GEOMETRY FC that had an arc (via ArcCatalog) and pasted it as an SDO_GEOMETRY FC. And the arc was preserved.
- I had wondered if the arc might have been densified into straight-line segments. But that didn't happen.

[image]

Comment: ArcGIS supports CAD objects ***in parallel*** to geometry, as a BLOB data type. The SDE.ST_GEOMETRY stores an *approximation* of the true curve object. SDO_GEOMETRY can store true curves, but Esri might not use it, since they use the BLOB instead. You need to review this Answer to make sure that the curve segment type is stored in SDO_GEOMETRY, not just that it looks right in an Esri client (leveraging the CAD BLOB).

Comment: @Vince Is the CAD BLOB stored inside the SHAPE column (within the user-defined object type)? Or is the CAD BLOB stored as it's own column in the table?

Comment: Usually in a separate column (can vary by implementation)