# What column is true curve data stored in? (SDE.ST_GEOMETRY for Oracle)

Tags: geometry, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, arcgis-10.7, st-geometry

I have an Oracle 18c SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polyline FC:

[image]

The lines in the FC have **true curves** (aka CAD BLOBs).

[image]

---

**Question: What column is the true curves data stored in?**

- [@Vince  mentioned  in a comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422814/does-oracles-sdo-geometry-spatial-type-support-arcs/422815?noredirect=1#comment689590_422815) that they're often stored in their own BLOB column in the table (depending on implementation). But in my case, I don't see any BLOB columns in my FC.
- Is the CAD BLOB stored within the SHAPE column — as a so-called "attribute" of the user-defined object type?
- Or somewhere else?

---

When I search for the words *"BLOB", "binary", or "byte"* in the [ST_Geometry in Oracle](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/stgeometry-oracle.htm) docs, I see a few different terms:

> - "ATTRIBUTE_BINARY  |  BLOB"
> - "Points: Contains the byte stream of the point coordinates that define the geometry"
> - "How ST_Geometry stores spatial data — POINTS | BLOB"
> - "ST_Geometry types | BLOB_ARRAY_TAB"

But can't really tell if any of those things contains the CAD BLOB or not.

Comment: ST_Geometry is a certain kind of BLOB and your geometries are there.

Comment: sdo_elem_info_array elements, and etype/interpretation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971693/sql-query-to-determine-if-oracle-spatial-table-contains-curves

Comment: @Mapperz This question is about the Esri SDE.ST_Geometry type, not SDO_GEOMETRY.

Comment: It's in the LOB type in a way you can't directly access from SQL, so the point is moot. The CAD object (and annotation) is stored in a separate BLOB column when an SDE.ST_GEOMETRY is not available (and the format is undocumented, so not of much use even then).

Comment: @Vince Thanks. True, although now that I understand that the CAD BLOB is stored within the SHAPE column, it helps me understand things a bit better -- when working with ArcPy as well. What I mean is: I've been trying to update vertices via ArcPy too. [See script here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvOPX.png). That ArcPy script reconstructs/replaces the SHAPE column, and therefore removes the arcs from lines (which isn't what I want). If the CAD BLOB was in it's own column, then it wouldn't be a problem. But the CAD BLOB is in the shape, which I replace, so that's why my curves disappear.